# C# XML Serialisation of Object that has an Object field without namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an Object into XML which has an 'Object' field. I want to achieve XML with no namespaces or attributes. I am able to remove the namespace of the root element, however, the Object element remains having a namespace.

My Object to serialize;

```
public class Message {
        public String Metadata { get; set; }
        public Object Payload { get; set; }


        public Message() {
        }

        public Message(String Metadata, Object Payload) {
            this.Metadata = Metadata;
            this.Payload = Payload;
        }
    }
```

How I serialize;

```
var s = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
var ns = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
s.Serialize(writer, payload, ns);
writer.Close();
```

My output:

```
<Message>
  <Metadata>myMetadata</Metadata>
  <Payload xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d2p1:type="q1:string" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">myPayload</Payload>
</Message>
```

My ideal output:

```
<Message>
  <Metadata>myMetadata</Metadata>
  <Payload>myPayload</Payload>
</Message>
```

I am a Java developer, and this is my first day doing C#! So apologies if I am missing anything obvious.

(My main goal is to end up having the following output)

```
<Message>
  <Metadata>myMetadata</Metadata>
  <Payload class="aClass">myPayload</Payload>
</Message>
```

But I can look into that myself once I have found a solution to the above problem!

Comment: I am wanting to send a c# Object to Java. I can get the Metadata back in Java fine, but the serialisation of 'Payload', as it is of type 'Object', is not able to be unserialised back in Java correctly. For example, when sending new Message("myMD", "myPL") to Java, my Java methods getMetadata() returns "myMD" and getPayload() returns java.lang.Object@343dsds - not "myPL"

Comment: What does that have to do with the namespaces? Java is simply not going to understand Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` attribute is necessary in order to be able to deserialize the `Payload` property; if the serializer doesn't know the type of the content, how can it deserialize it?

Normally the namespaces are added to the root element, but you explicitly prevented that by specifying a `XmlSerializerNamespaces` with an empty mapping, so the namespace is added on the `Payload` element instead.

If you use `XmlSerializer`, the best you can do is this:

```
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Metadata>myMetadata</Metadata>
  <Payload xsi:type="xsd:string">myPayload</Payload>
</Message>
```

Now, you could of course generate the XML manually, without any namespace, but then you would need some way of knowing the type of `Payload` for deserialization.